# Matrices with real exponents

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $B$ is an invertible matrix.

Show that for any real number $t$, $$(BAB^*)^t= BA^{\frac{1}{2}}(A^{\frac{1}{2}}B^*BA^{\frac{1}{2}})^{t-1}A^{\frac{1}{2}}B^*$$

If $t$ is a natural number it is trivial. But how can I solve it for real numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $P$ is positive definite and $P=QDQ^\ast$ is a unitary diagonalisation, $P^t$ is defined to be $QD^tQ^\ast$ for any real number $t$. Now, let $A^{1/2}B^\ast=USV^\ast$ be a singular value decomposition. Then
\begin{aligned}
BA^{1/2}(A^{1/2}B^\ast BA^{1/2})^{t-1}A^{1/2}B^\ast
&=VSU^\ast(US^2U^\ast)^{t-1}USV^\ast\\
&=VSU^\ast(US^{2(t-1)}U^\ast)USV^\ast\\
&=VS^{2t}V^\ast\\
&=(VS^2V^\ast)^t\\
&=(BAB^\ast)^t.
\end{aligned}